# React : How to redirect from Login page to AppLayout page based on status code 200?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, axios, create-react-app

hi everyone and thanks for your time to read this.
I'm rather new to this and I appreciate any help you might consider.

The client insisted in doing the authentication on its own in jQuery (for safety reasons) which I've linked in the Index.html. Upon authentication successful, the jQuery responds with an alert window containing [object Object].

I've been told to redirect from Login page to AppLayout page based on the status code 200 and I can't find anything on react docs about this or if even it's possible.

My interaction with the server is through Swagger API.
I'm using create-react-app with react-router and axios for all other API requests.

Is there a way to target the status code and based on that condition to do the redirect?

Otherwise can you suggest safest authentication method using axios only and just get rid of the jQuery?

I know it's far fetch but any suggestions/links are greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible. The best option would be to perform the authentication in-app using axios. The implementation details will depend of your version of React-Router. Assuming v4, you can use history.push('/new-route') method to navigate you to a new route that is within app. Alternatively, you can use a Redirect component that performs a similar function. See docs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect.

With Redirect it would look like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.userIsAuthed) {
    return <Redirect to='/app' />
  }
  return <LoginInternals />
}
```

If you can do your POST in app, you'll set userIsAuthed to true in the POST success handler.

If you really want to do it using jQuery on the outside, you could store the success info in a cookie or local storage. In your react Login route, in componentWillMount, you can check cookie or local storage for your success info and update state accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-router hooks

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"
const history = useHistory()
if(response.status === 200){
    history.push('/path')
  }
```